# Protected destructor and object initialisation

Tags: c++

see the following code :

```
struct A
{
protected:
    ~A() {};
};
void main()
{
    //case 1:
    A a;
    //error C2248: 'A::~A': cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'

    //case 2:
    A b();//works fine
}
```

why do I get error in case-1 but not in case-2?
many thanks

Comment: case 2 is [most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work), you declared a function that returns `A`

Comment: You are talking about a private (actually, protected in your code) **destructor**, not _deconstructor_

Comment: @GianPaolo I've updated the title to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case 1 occurs because you declared the destructor as `protected` so when you locally declared the object, your program can't access the destructor which is needed to destroy the object.

If you declared a derived object then the derived object would have access to the base class's destructor:

```
struct B : public A
{}
```

then in your `main` you had `B b;` instead of `A a;` then it would compile without error.

For case 2 is [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work):

```
A b();
```

is a function declaration, it's not doing what you think which is to create an instance of `A`

Comment: @MEMS because `main()` needs to call `A::~A()` to unwind the stack, but it can't, because it is protected. In almost all cases you don't want to make the destructor anything but public.